# How to get Url of my web application but without HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring-boot, url

I want to get the current url of my application in Java Spring boot. But the problem is, I want to get that from the `util` class and not from `Controller`. I tried to get this from `HttpServletRequest`  but I am unable to import its package into my `util` class.

Please help me to get the URL of my website which should not be hardcoded. Or if there is a way to use `HttpServletRequest` into my util class.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the url for example in your service you can annotate with `@Autowired` an `HttpServletRequest` as follow:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;



    public String getCurrentUrl() {
        return httpServletRequest.getURL().toString();
    }
}
```

You can use the same technique in any Component, so any object created by spring. It works if you are executing code directly from an http request. It means that you can't use it for example in a different thread started from the thread receiving the http request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer sir but I am unable to import its package. I was thinking to use any other technique to get the URL of my web application

Comment: You need to pass the HttpServletRequest and extract the address from the utility class. The annotation @Autowired let you use a wrapper of the HttpServletRequest that is set up by spring for every request. What package are you unable to import?

Comment: I am unable to import import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO Is it possible to create a utility class to get request information extracting from  `HttpServletRequest`? For example, I want to create a utility class (Not Spring Bean) and whenever I need to get request data I can get like, `MyCustomUtil.getMyCustomParameter();` or `MyCustomUtil.getMyCustomHeader();`. Thanks